# Elasticsearch search API does not return results when called with document type

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to retrieve data from ES using the search API.
The name of the index is `index_certificate` and the document type is `doc_certificate`.

Below API call works fine and returns results.

```
curl -X POST "http://elasticsearch:9200/index_certificate/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "district_id": {
              "query": "10"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

But if I add the document type to the url without changing any other thing as below, it returns an empty result array. (Does not throw any errors)

```
curl -X POST "http://elasticsearch:9200/index_certificate/doc_certificate/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' { "query": { "bool": { "must": [ { "match": { "district_id": { "query": "10" } } } ] } } }'
```

I am not the one who did setup the node. Also this is not a production node. I am not sure whether this can be due to a read/write permission issue related to the document. I appreciate if someone can help me to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the top of the results you get from the working query?

Comment: @Val it's like this. {
  "took" : 24,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index_certificate",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3502492",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@version" : "1",
          "created_by" : 160,
          "creator_first_name" : "Migration", ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see the `_type` of your documents is `_doc` and not `doc_certificate`

So the following would work:

```
curl -X POST "http://elasticsearch:9200/index_certificate/_doc/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' { "query": { "bool": { "must": [ { "match": { "district_id": { "query": "10" } } } ] } } }'
```

Comment: OMG! How can that happen? I will check and come back.

Comment: In ES 7, there's [no types anymore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html)